# How to avoid an error due to special characters in search string when using Regex for a simple search in Swift?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, uitextview

I'm using Regex to search for a word in a textView. I implemented a textField and two switch as options (Whole words and Match case). All work fine when you enter a plain word in the search filed but I get an error when I enter a special character like \ or *.

The error I get is like this one:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “*” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue=*}
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem and have the code handle all the text like plain text?

Because I would like to search also for special characters, I would like to prefer to not interdict to enter them. At the beginning I though to programmatically add an escape backslash to all special character before to perform a search, but maybe there are some more smart approaches?

Here is the code I'm using (based on this tutorial: [NSRegularExpression Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial))

```
struct SearchOptions {
    let searchString: String
    var replacementString: String
    let matchCase: Bool
    let wholeWords: Bool
}

extension NSRegularExpression {
    convenience init?(options: SearchOptions) {
        let searchString = options.searchString
        let isCaseSensitive = options.matchCase
        let isWholeWords = options.wholeWords

        // handle case sensitive option
        var regexOption: NSRegularExpressionOptions = .CaseInsensitive
        if isCaseSensitive { // if it is match case remove case sensitive option
            regexOption = []
        }

        // put the search string in the pattern
        var pattern = searchString
        // if it's whole word put the string between word boundary \b
        if isWholeWords {
            pattern = "\\b\(searchString)\\b" // the second \ is used as escape
        }

        do {
            try self.init(pattern: pattern, options: regexOption)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/escapedPatternForString:

Comment: Try `pattern = "(?<!\\w)" + NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString) + "(?!\\w)"`

Comment: Thank you for the comment Wiktor, actually I don't want to avoid or ignoring special characters being entered in a search bar, but find a way to search for what the user enter and handle as plain text instead of ignoring or removing something was entered in the search box.

Comment: But doesn't `var pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString)` solve your issue? Or, perhaps, you just need to pass [`IgnoreMetacharacters` option](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@NSRegularExpressionOptions)?

Comment: Hi  Wiktor, yes `var pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString)` works fine, thank you. Could you post it as answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/escapedPatternForString:):

> Returns a string by adding backslash escapes as necessary to protect any characters that would match as pattern metacharacters.

Thus, you need

```
var pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString)
```

Also, note that this piece:

```
if isWholeWords {
    pattern = "\\b\(searchString)\\b"
```

might fail if a user inputs `(text)` and wishes to search for it as a  whole word. The best way to match whole words is by means of lookarounds disallowing word chars on both ends of the search word:

```
if isWholeWords {
    pattern = "(?<!\\w)" + NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString) + "(?!\\w)"
```