# How to use Regular Expression in Swift to replace matching expressions with the template string instead of plain text

Tags: ios, regex, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a project with a main textView and two textFields. In the main textView field there is  the text to process, in the first textField you enter a regular expression and in the second textField you enter the substitution template string.

If in the second textField I enter text, all work fine, but if I enter some regex it seems that this is handled like plain text. For example entering \n\n instead of adding two newlines characters in the final text, it just enter nn.

Here is my code, it's partially based on

- this answer by OOPer:
  [How to check in Swift if a Regular Expression is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385539/how-to-check-in-swift-if-a-regular-expression-is-valid)
  and
- this answer by Wiktor Stribiżew:
  [How to avoid an error due to special characters in search string when using Regex for a simple search in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375557/how-to-avoid-an-error-due-to-special-characters-in-search-string-when-using-rege)

What am I doing wrong?

```
if let regex =  NSRegularExpression.expresssionWith(theSearchOptions){ // theSearchOptions uses the struct below

    // replace matches
    let regStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count), withTemplate: substitution) // EDIT: substitution is the var that contains the template string
    newStr = regStr
}


struct SearchOptions {
    let searchString: String
    var replacementString: String
    let matchCase: Bool
    let wholeWords: Bool
    let escapeMetacharacters: Bool
}

extension NSRegularExpression {
    static func expresssionWith(options: SearchOptions) -> NSRegularExpression? {
        let searchString = options.searchString
        let isCaseSensitive = options.matchCase // true
        let isWholeWords = options.wholeWords // false
        let escapeMetacharacters = options.escapeMetacharacters // false

        // handle case sensitive option
        var regexOption: NSRegularExpressionOptions = .CaseInsensitive
        if isCaseSensitive { // if it is match case remove case sensitive option
            regexOption = []
        }

        // put the search string in the pattern
        var pattern = searchString

        if escapeMetacharacters {
            pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString)
            // adding backslash escapes as necessary to protect any characters that would match as pattern metacharacters
        } else {
            // no changes in the pattern
        }

        if isWholeWords {
            pattern = "(?<!\\w)" + NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(searchString) + "(?!\\w)"
        }

        do {
            return try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: regexOption)
        } catch  {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before applying the regex substitution, replace all `\n` (the two char sequence `"\\n"`) with a newline.

Comment: Thank you for your hep Wiktor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know textField does not convert user inputs, so entering `\n\n` will make 4 character String `\` `n` `\` `n`.

And regex templates do not recognize much escaping sequence as compared to regex patterns.

[Template Matching Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW46)

[Regular Expression Metacharacters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48)

As you see only two metacharacters are defined: `$` and `\`.
And `\` is defined as:

> Treat the following character as a literal, suppressing any special
>   meaning. Backslash escaping in substitution text is only required for
>   '$' and '\', but may be used on any other character without bad
>   effects.

This description means that any character following `\` is treated as the character itself. Supplying `\n\n` as a template is exactly the same as `nn`.

As Wiktor Stribiżew already commented, if you want to give special meaning to some character sequences, you need to do it yourself.

```
if let regex =  NSRegularExpression.expresssionWith(theSearchOptions){ // theSearchOptions uses the struct below
    //Replace metacharacters in `substitution` (Assuming `substitution` is a var.)
    substitution = substitution.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: "\n")
    substitution = substitution.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\r", withString: "\r")
    substitution = substitution.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\t", withString: "\t")
    //You may need more...

    // replace matches
    let regStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count), withTemplate: substitution)
    newStr = regStr
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation and especially for the code OOPer, now everything is clear... and it works!